# Splitting a Long String into smaller strings

Tags: string, r, split

I have a dataframe that includes a column of numbers like this:

```
360010001001002
360010001001004
360010001001005
360010001001006
```

I'd like to break into chunks of 2 digits, 3 digits, 5 digits, 1 digit, 4 digits:

```
36 001 00010 0 1002
36 001 00010 0 1004
36 001 00010 0 1005
36 001 00010 0 1006
```

That seems like it should be straightforward but I'm reading the strsplit documentation and I can't sort out how I'd do this by lengths.

Comment: Is your main intent a) to **convert a vector of substring lengths into pairs of indices** or
b) **splitting into d.f. columns, and doing that efficiently** : break the chunks out as new separate d.f. columns (-> ddply(transform,...)), or just do some string manipulation (e.g. insert '-') on the same column? (-> ldply)

Comment: My problem is long solved, but since you asked ... yeah: I wanted those chunks as separate columns. They're an ID number. I would have to go back and look exactly, but the chunks have meaning: `36` is state, `001` county, `00010` census block or something.

Comment: Right, but my question a) was it doesn't really matter to you whether you specify an arbitrary vector of `widths = c(2,3,5,1,4)` rather than plain old pairs of indices: (1,2), (3,5), (6,10), (11,11), (12,15). Several answerers got hung up on whether that cumulative-index-arithmetic was a key part of your question. Turns out it wasn't. You could reword for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this data:

```
x <- c("360010001001002", "360010001001004", "360010001001005", "360010001001006")
```

try this:

```
read.fwf(textConnection(x), widths = c(2, 3, 5, 1, 4))
```

If `x` is numeric then replace `x` with `as.character(x)` in this statement.

Comment: I wound up doing this: `foo$county_id <- as.vector(gsub(foo$fullfipsid, pattern = "..(...).*", replace="\\1"))` for each chunk. Worked. But I'm accepting this answer b/c it is elegant and also works. (I tested it)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `substring` (assuming the length of string/number is fixed):

```
xx <- c(360010001001002, 360010001001004, 360010001001005, 360010001001006)
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(xx, function(x) as.numeric(substring(x, 
                     c(1,3,6,11,12), c(2,5,10,11,15)))))
out <- as.data.frame(out)
```

Comment: `ddply(mutate...)` seems more elegant than `do.call(rbind,...)` ? See my answer below.

Comment: and `cumsum()` for accumulating indices

Answer (score 4):

A functional version:

```
split.fixed.len <- function(x, lengths) {
   cum.len <- c(0, cumsum(lengths))
   start   <- head(cum.len, -1) + 1
   stop    <- tail(cum.len, -1)
   mapply(substring, list(x), start, stop)
}    

a <- c(360010001001002,
       360010001001004,
       360010001001005,
       360010001001006)

split.fixed.len(a, c(2, 3, 5, 1, 4))
#      [,1] [,2]  [,3]    [,4] [,5]  
# [1,] "36" "001" "00010" "0"  "1002"
# [2,] "36" "001" "00010" "0"  "1004"
# [3,] "36" "001" "00010" "0"  "1005"
# [4,] "36" "001" "00010" "0"  "1006"
```

Answer (score 0):

(Wow, this task is incredibly clunky and painful compared to Python. Anyhoo...)

PS I see now your main intent was to convert a vector of substring lengths into pairs of indices.
You could use `cumsum()`, then sort the indices all together:

```
ll <- c(2,3,5,1,4)
sort( c(1, cumsum(ll), (cumsum(ll)+1)[1:(length(ll)-1)]) )
# now extract these as pairs.
```

But it's quite painful. [flodel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201032/flodel)'s answer for that is better.

As to the actual task of splitting into d.f. columns, and doing that efficiently:

`stringr::str_sub()` combines elegantly with `plyr::ddply()` / `ldply`

```
require(plyr)
require(stringr)

df <- data.frame(value=c(360010001001002,360010001001004,360010001001005,360010001001006))
df$valc = as.character(df$value)

df <- ddply(df, .(value), mutate, chk1=str_sub(valc,1,2), chk3=str_sub(valc,3,5), chk6=str_sub(valc,6,10), chk11=str_sub(valc,11,11), chk14=str_sub(valc,12,15) )

#             value            valc chk1 chk3  chk6 chk11 chk14
# 1 360010001001002 360010001001002   36  001 00010     0  1002
# 2 360010001001004 360010001001004   36  001 00010     0  1004
# 3 360010001001005 360010001001005   36  001 00010     0  1005
# 4 360010001001006 360010001001006   36  001 00010     0  1006
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function from `stringi` package

```
splitpoints <- cumsum(c(2, 3, 5, 1,4))
stri_sub("360010001001002",c(1,splitpoints[-length(splitpoints)]+1),splitpoints)
```